# Split records based on Startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, oracle

Input set,

```
CMP BND_CD STARTDATE  ENDDATE
01  UF     03/15/2010 07/01/2010
01  TRL    03/15/2010 12/15/2014
```

Dummy Data

```
CREATE TABLE DATA ( CMP, BND_CD, STARTDATE, ENDDATE ) AS
  SELECT '01','UF',  DATE '2010-03-15', DATE '2010-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '01','TRL', DATE '2010-03-15', DATE '2010-12-15' FROM DUAL;
```

I need the output as 3 records, which split the TRL/UF records, ie,

```
CMP BND_CD STARTDATE  ENDDATE
01  UF     03/15/2010 07/01/2010
01  TRL    03/15/2010 07/01/2010
01  TRL    07/01/2010 12/15/2014
```

The split should be done for each CMP code for the two BND_CD, if the date ranges overlaps each other.We have to group the records based on CMP value, then If TRL overlaps UF, TRL reords should be splitted,or if UFoverlaps TRL, UF records should be splitted.

Comment: What if you had more rows, for exampe another row with start/end = 04/01/2010 - 08/01/2010?

Comment: @Aleksej Then we should create one more interval, as a new record. We have to group the records based on CMP value, then If TRL overlaps UF, TRL reords should be splitted,or if UFoverlaps TRL, UF records should be splitted.

Comment: @Aleksej If 04/01/2010 - 08/01/2010 is added as a TRL record, then UF should get splitted between 03/15/2010 - 04/01/2010, 04/01/2010-07/01/2010. Or If 04/01/2010 - 08/01/2010 is added as a UF record, then TRL should get splitted between 03/15/2010 - 04/01/2010, 04/01/2010-07/01/2010,-07/01/2010-08/01/2010,08/01/2010-12/15/2014.

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi Please do not add test cases in comments - edit them into the answer. I have edited your answer with the sample data but I was not 100% sure of what your expected output was; so please edit the areas where i have left question marks to clarify.

Comment: @MT0 If I add more scenario, will it complicate the question?

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi It is better to ask the question you want answering (and include the appropriate edge cases) rather than getting answers to the question you actually asked that do not entirely solve your problem. As it stands your first example is very simple and answers that solve that would almost certainly not work for either of the latter two cases which are more complicated - so, if you only want the simple case solved then rollback my edit (or re-edit it) but if your problem is more complicated then please provide the appropriate information.

Comment: @MT0 I tried including the test cases, but it spoils the readability of the question, So I thought of keeping it short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**:

```
SELECT u.cmp,          -- UF values preceding the TRL range
       u.bnd_cd,
       u.start_date,
       LEAST( u.end_date, t.start_date )
FROM   data t
       INNER JOIN
       data u
       ON (    t.bnd_cd = 'TRL'
           AND u.bnd_cd = 'UF'
           AND t.cmp = u.cmp
           AND u.start_date < t.start_date )
UNION ALL
SELECT u.cmp,          -- UF values within the TRL range
       u.bnd_cd,
       GREATEST( u.start_date, t.start_date ),
       LEAST( u.end_date, t.end_date )
FROM   data t
       INNER JOIN
       data u
       ON (    t.bnd_cd = 'TRL'
           AND u.bnd_cd = 'UF'
           AND t.cmp = u.cmp
           AND u.start_date <= t.end_date
           AND u.end_date   >= t.start_date )
UNION ALL
SELECT u.cmp,          -- UF values following the TRL range
       u.bnd_cd,
       GREATEST( u.start_date, t.end_date ),
       u.end_date
FROM   data t
       INNER JOIN
       data u
       ON (    t.bnd_cd = 'TRL'
           AND u.bnd_cd = 'UF'
           AND t.cmp = u.cmp
           AND u.end_date > t.end_date )
UNION ALL
SELECT t.cmp,          -- TRL values preceding the UF range
       t.bnd_cd,
       t.start_date,
       LEAST( t.end_date, u.start_date )
FROM   data t
       INNER JOIN
       data u
       ON (    t.bnd_cd = 'TRL'
           AND u.bnd_cd = 'UF'
           AND t.cmp = u.cmp
           AND t.start_date < u.start_date )
UNION ALL
SELECT t.cmp,          -- TRL values within the UF range
       t.bnd_cd,
       GREATEST( t.start_date, u.start_date ),
       LEAST( t.end_date, u.end_date )
FROM   data t
       INNER JOIN
       data u
       ON (    t.bnd_cd = 'TRL'
           AND u.bnd_cd = 'UF'
           AND t.cmp = u.cmp
           AND t.start_date <= u.end_date
           AND t.end_date   >= u.start_date )
UNION ALL
SELECT t.cmp,          -- TRL values following the UF range
       t.bnd_cd,
       GREATEST( t.start_date, u.end_date ),
       t.end_date
FROM   data t
       INNER JOIN
       data u
       ON (    t.bnd_cd = 'TRL'
           AND u.bnd_cd = 'UF'
           AND t.cmp = u.cmp
           AND t.end_date > u.end_date )
```

**Output**:

```
CMP BND_CD START_DATE END_DATE
--- ------ ---------- ----------
01  UF     2010-03-15 2010-07-01
01  TRL    2010-03-15 2010-07-01
01  TRL    2010-07-01 2010-08-01
```